# Does sql queries block node.js event loop?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, event-loop

I'm going to create a web-api using pure node.js that do CRUD operations on SQL Server and return results to clients. The queries are almost long running (around 3 seconds) and request per second is high (around 30 rps). I'm using mssql package with a call back function to return result once it's ready.
I've already read a lot about node and I know its quite fits for IO intensive not CPU intensive apps and also event loop shouldn't be blocked because it's single threaded...

My question: Is Node.js suitable for this (SQL intensive) scenario? Is there any performance issue to use Node.js for this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js has gone all-in on non-blocking code to the degree that pretty much any function that's blocking in the [Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/index.html) will be labelled as `Sync`.

Every database driver I've seen follows the model of requiring callbacks, using Promises, or [in some cases both](http://sequelizejs.com).

As a Node.js developer you must read the documentation carefully to look for any potentially blocking calls, and need to employ the correct concurrency method to handle asynchronous operations. Normally you don't need to overly concern yourself with the details of how long any given operation is, but you should be still be careful when doing things that are slow. Process data in smaller chunks (e.g. row by row) instead of all at once.

Even though it's just single threaded, Node.js can perform very well under load because it's very quick to switch between asynchronous operations. You can also scale up by having multiple Node.js processes working in parallel quite easily, especially if you're using a message bus or HTTP-type fan-out through a load balancer.

Comment: Based on your ideas and node documents finally I decided to use .net core instead. Thanks

Comment: That's your call, but there's really no reason to think that Node.js will be slow. In my experience it's always ridiculously efficient and wildly exceeds expectations.